# React Native: Prefico de um auxílio para resolver o erro 'Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop'

Tags: react, react-native

Sou novato no desenvolvimento react native e estou preso em um erro que não consigo resolver. Esse erro passou a apresentar após eu criar um componente customizado para mostrar um dialog usandom o react-native-paper e chamar esse componete na minha tela de criação de usuário SignUp.js. Abaixo segue os códigos das telas.

'SignUp.js'

```
import React, {useState, useContext} from 'react';
import {TextInput, Button} from 'react-native-paper';
import {AuthContext} from '../../context/AuthContext'; // Importe o contexto de autenticação
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
//import CreateUser_Fb from '../../data/firebase/loginFirebase';
import CustomDialog from '../../components/dialogs/CustomDialog';

const SignUp = ({navigation}) => {
  const {loadingAuth} = useContext(AuthContext); // Use a função de criar usuário do contexto

  const [name, setName] = useState('luciano');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('xxxxxx@example.com');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('123');
  const [telephone, setTelephone] = useState('11999999999');

  //controles do dialog
  const [visibleDialog, setVisibleDialog] = useState(false);
  const [titleDialog, setTitleDialog] = useState(false);
  const [messageDialog, setMessageDialog] = useState(false);

  const showDialog = (title, message) => {
    setVisibleDialog(true);
    setTitleDialog(title);
    setMessageDialog(message);
  };

  const hideDialog = () => {
    setVisibleDialog(false);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        mode="outlined"
        label="Nome"
        value={name}
        onChangeText={text => setName(text)}
        style={styles.input}
      />
      <TextInput
        mode="outlined"
        label="Email"
        value={email}
        onChangeText={text => setEmail(text)}
        style={styles.input}
      />
      <TextInput
        mode="outlined"
        label="Telefone"
        value={telephone}
        onChangeText={text => setTelephone(text)}
        style={styles.input}
      />
      <TextInput
        mode="outlined"
        label="Senha"
        value={password}
        onChangeText={text => setPassword(text)}
        secureTextEntry
        style={styles.input}
      />
      <Button
        mode="contained"
        onPress={showDialog('Teste', 'Testando')}
        style={styles.button}
        loading={loadingAuth}>
        Cadastrar
      </Button>

      {visibleDialog && (
        <CustomDialog
          title={titleDialog}
          message={messageDialog}
          visible={visibleDialog}
          onClose={hideDialog}></CustomDialog>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  input: {
    marginBottom: 15,
  },
  button: {
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  signupButton: {
    marginTop: 20,
  },
});

export default SignUp;
```

e o componente 'CustomDialog.js'

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Button as PaperButton,
  Paragraph,
  Dialog,
  Portal,
} from 'react-native-paper';

const CustomDialog = props => {
  return (
    <Portal>
      <Dialog visible={props.visible} onDismiss={() => props.onClose()}>
        <Dialog.Title>{props.title}</Dialog.Title>
        <Dialog.Content>
          <Paragraph>{props.message}</Paragraph>
        </Dialog.Content>
        <Dialog.Actions>
          <PaperButton onPress={() => props.onClose()}>OK</PaperButton>
        </Dialog.Actions>
      </Dialog>
    </Portal>
  );
};

export default CustomDialog;
```

Não chamo o provider do react-native-paper ai, porque o chamo no App.js.

Alguém poderia me ajudar a identificar o problema?